# Upload app to playstore error related to permission

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, android-permissions

I am trying to upload my ReactNative app to play store but it gives below error -

> Upload failed
>   Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.READ_CONTACTS).

i am not using Camera and contacts in my app, and not declare permissions for same in manifest but after generating signed apk it gives error mention above.

Any help really appreciated, i am not able to upload app to play store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of any **third-party npm package** which may include that permission so from my experience in this field You have to add the privacy policy regarding to that particular information it means if you ask get accounts permission in your app then you have to declare that with your privacy policy file we use that data i.e. email address or whatever with reasons.

**Therefore need a privacy policy for the app If your app handles personal or sensitive user data**

[View Official Informations](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?visit_id=1-636181561830097288-1046519841&rd=1#privacy)

**Also can do this**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: @RaviBhandari Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the legal documents for your app
check out the link below for more information

https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/3744-how-to-add-android-and-ios-mobile-permissions-for-device-data#android